# select a max of 3 checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of colors and want the user to select max 3.
When the user selects the 4th the initial selected box should get unchecked (less than 3 is fine). When the user selects the color it should trigger and event as i will be sending this via XMLHttpRequest later.

I need to send a max of 3 colors as c1= & c2= & c3=

Please explain how to get it i'm very new to this..

```js
var queue = [];

function check(val1) {
  if (document.getElementById(val1).prop('checked', true))
    queue.push(val1);
  //alert(queue[0] + '-' + queue[1] + '-' + queue[2]);
  if (queue.length > 3) {
    var val2 = queue.shift();
    queue.push(val1);
    //alert(queue[0] + '-' + queue[1] + '-' + queue[2]);
    document.getElementById(val2).prop('checked', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="red" id="red">
<div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="blue" id="blue">
<div style="background-color:blue; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="green" id="green">
<div style="background-color:green; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="yellow" id="yellow">
<div style="background-color:yellow; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="orange" id="orange">
<div style="background-color:orange; width:50px; height:25px; "></div>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="black" id="black">
<div style="background-color:black; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
```

Comment: You can probably simply store an array of selected check boxes. When the array size is 3, and a new one is checked, remove the first element whilst deselecting it, and append the new one to the array (thus always maintaining no more than 3 at any time).

Comment: Just a suggestion: Unchecking the checkbox the user chose first when more than 3 checkbox are checked is not user friendly. You should disable unchecked checkboxs when three are checked.

Comment: thats what i have tried here... but it refuses to deselect the first one.. its getting the value but .prop('checked', false) doesnt work

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon how do i disable all others?

Comment: @user2296208 like this http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5Hv/8/

Comment: See Here http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5Hv/11/, and see my answer below for the detailed explanation.  Also, don't forget to accept the best answer that works for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your `check` function like this:

```
function check(val1) {
    var chk_arr =  document.getElementsByName("chk");
    var chklength = chk_arr.length;             
    var tot = 0;
    var i = -1;
    for(k=0;k< chklength;k++) {
        if (chk_arr[k].checked) { 
            tot++; 
            if (i < 0) i = k;
        }
        if (tot > 3) { chk_arr[i].checked = false; }
    } 
}
```

Just provide a common name to all checkboxes. This way no need to pass `this` from each checkbox.

See the updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5Hv/7/**

Comment: i changed the whole .prop(...) to checked=true/false
that did it

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkboxs a class name chk, so the html would be:

```
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="red" id="red">
<div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="blue" id="blue">
<div style="background-color:blue; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="green" id="green">
<div style="background-color:green; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="yellow" id="yellow">
<div style="background-color:yellow; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="orange" id="orange">
<div style="background-color:orange; width:50px; height:25px; "></div>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" onchange="check(this.value)" value="black" id="black">
<div style="background-color:black; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
```

And in the jquery you can do like this:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
$(function(){
  $('.chk').click(function(){
    if(count > 3) { count = 0; return;}
    else{
      if($(this).prop('checked')){
         // do something
         count++;
      }
    }
  });
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED:  This will work for what you are asking: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg5Hv/11/

```
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" value="red" id="red">
        <div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="blue">
        <div style="background-color:blue; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="green" id="green">
        <div style="background-color:green; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" id="yellow">
        <div style="background-color:yellow; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="orange" id="orange">
        <div style="background-color:orange; width:50px; height:25px; "></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="black" id="black">
        <div style="background-color:black; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>

        <script>
            var array = [];
            $("input").change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    array.push(this.id);
                    if (array.length > 3) {
                        array.splice(0, 1);
                    }
                    $("input").prop("checked", false);
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        $("#" + array[i]).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var index = array.indexOf(this.id);
                    array.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

(Had to update, I forgot to remove the element if the checkbox was manually unchecked)

Here's how it works:

First, create an array to hold all of the id's of the checkboxes that are being checked.

Add an event handler to each checkbox.

If the checkbox is checked, Add the id to the array.

If the length of the array is greater than 3, remove the first id from the array.

Uncheck all of the checkboxes, then check only the boxes that are in the array.

If the user manually unchecks a box, then remove it from the array.

Let me know if you have any other questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdpu4L26/2/) I did for another question has a maximum of two checkboxes implemented. I use,

```
$(parentId).find(":checkbox:checked").length < 2
```

to allow the check to happen.